# How to manage/stop spring 4 ConcurrentTaskScheduler

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am using Spring 4. I use this for execute a task periodically for web sockets:

```
private TaskScheduler scheduler = new ConcurrentTaskScheduler();
```

In my class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableScheduling
@Component
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;


    private TaskScheduler scheduler = new ConcurrentTaskScheduler();
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/simplemessages").withSockJS();
    }

    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {

        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic/", "/queue/");

        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }


    @PostConstruct
    private void broadcastTimePeriodically() {


        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String statStr = "Server Response" + new Date();
                System.out.println("thread schedular run time :" + Hello.printTime());
                try {
                    template.convertAndSend("/topic/simplemessagesresponse", statStr);
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    System.err.println("!!!!!! websocket timer error :>" + e.toString());
                }

            }
        }, 4000));


}

@PreDestroy
private void destroyServices() {
    scheduler = null; // how to destroy ? 

}

public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {

}

public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.taskExecutor().corePoolSize(4).maxPoolSize(10);
}

public boolean configureMessageConverters(List < MessageConverter > arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}
@Override
public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration arg0) {

}
}
```

I want to know to things:

1. I found that the scheduler is running twice within 4000 milliseconds. How is it happening and how can I stop it?
2. I run this application in tomcat. As you can see, the method `destroyServices()` needs to destroy the schedular. Here the problem is, even the tomcat is restarted again, previously running thread is still running. So when the tomcat is going to down, that thread also should be terminated. I need to know How I can destroy it on tomcat is going to down or any system crash?

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet is from documentation of `@EnableScheduling`:

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableScheduling
   public class AppConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
       @Override
       public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
           taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
       }

       @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
       public Executor taskExecutor() {
           return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
       }
   }
```

I think you should get the bean named *taskExecutor* (in this case) and call `shutdown` (in fact depending on your configuration) method of it.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question with complete class. It is not clear for me that declaring the `@Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")`.