# Stop ConcurrentTaskScheduler when spring context closed

Tags: java, spring

I am writing a simple spring application with `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`. I have a `ConcurrentTaskScheduler` in my application. What is the best practice for stopping the `ConcurrentTaskScheduler` when the spring context closed?

Update: The main problem is when Junit close the context in @After annotation all threads will be terminated but when i manually close the context at the end of application, Some threads running by `ConcurrentTaskScheduler` will continue running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let Spring handle the shutdown itself.

Pass a ScheduledExecutorService to your ConcurrentTaskScheduler.
Than add a method with anotation @PreDestroy in which shutdown the ScheduledExecutorService.

```
    @PreDestroy
    public void cleanUp() throws InterruptedException {
        scheduleExecutorService.shutdown();
        try {
            scheduleExecutorService.awaitTermination(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            scheduleExecutorService.shutdownNow();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, ConcurrentTaskScheduler has the two mentioned methods?

Comment: Oh, I am really sorry I though you asked for ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. I have updated my answer for ConcurrentTaskScheduler

Comment: Just tell me, how do you - calling #shutdown directly - *letting Spring handle the shutdown itself* ....

Comment: @Antoniossss sorry, didn't get you! Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score -1):

What I do in my project is, I save the jobs in the database so I can have a control over it, so in the future I can just grab the information from it and stop.

[How to manage/stop spring 4 ConcurrentTaskScheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823337/how-to-manage-stop-spring-4-concurrenttaskscheduler)

Comment: Thanks, but i dont want to do that